# Transparency for image background in a table

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, opacity

I'm developing a website in PHP, HTML with CSS.

I'm developing a website and I need to insert a background image into a table, that's right, Now I can see the image when I request the webpage, but I need to add transparency to this image, I know that I can do it making the PNG with alfa transparency at percent what I want, but I prefer not process the image into a image editor due to the flexibilty that a parameter offers against a alpha image transparency inside the PNG.

I'm using this tag.

```
<table background="image.png">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
table {
  width: 200px; /* your width */
  height: 200px; /* your height */
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

table:after {
  content: "";
  background: url(image.png);
  opacity: 0.5; /* set your opacity */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/cW28y/)**